# Triple booting on a MacBook Pro

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mouse, macbook, refit

I am trying to triple-boot a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion, Windows 7, and Ubuntu.

However, after attempting to install `rEFit` (the boot screen never appears), I booted directly onto my Ubuntu installation disk by holding the <kbd>C</kbd> key. When I boot into the DVD, I receive this [screen](http://www.imgur.com/q4nTFM2.jpg) then I see the normal **Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu**.

However, after I select **Install Ubuntu** then **Something else** when it asks me how I want to install Ubuntu on my computer, the computer doesn't recognize my clicks properly anymore.

When I get to a popup screen of any kind (such as one asking me what format I want for a certain partition or which partition I want to use as swap space), the computer doesn't recognize the click *in* the pop-up box, but rather it registers the click as me clicking the table *behind* the popup box.

I am able to navigate using the keyboard, but it is cumbersome. Then, when I'm finally finished and click **Install**, it tells me I need a `Reserved Bios` partition or something like that. So I make a reserved bios partition out of a partition labeled *free space* that has 134 MB of space, and click **Install**. Then my computer completely stops responding.

I would really appreciate any help you might offer.

Comment: @Edwin Your edits are quite good. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You might try refind as refit is no longer active.